# Sequelize better way of writing this code

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I am using `NodeJS` and `sequelize`. I have two types of login in my application. One is normal user login and one is company login.

The code below looks for the token in the company table first, if it does not exist it moves to the user table to find it.

This way I know who has logged in to the system.

Is there a better way to do it?

OR

Is there a way where I can simultaneously search in two tables rather than waiting for `sequelize` to search in one table and then do the other?

```
var token = req.get('Auth') || '';
db.token.findOne({
    where:{
        tokenHash: cryptojs.MD5(token).toString()
    }
}).then(function(tokenInstance){
    if(!tokenInstance){
        throw new Error();
    }
    req.token = tokenInstance;
    return db.company_auth.findByToken(token); //looks in the first table (company)
}).then(function(entity){
    if(entity === null){
        return db.user.findByToken(token); //if not found (then looks in the second table - user)
    }else{
        req.entity = entity;   
        next(); 
    }
}).then(function(user){
    req.user = user;
    next();
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    res.status(401).send();
});
```

TIA!

Comment: yes you can.... there is

Comment: Your code currently calls `next()` twice. I don't think that's intended?

Comment: @Bergi that is actually intended because if token in the company table is found, it will just move on to do other stuff and not search in the user table.

Comment: @Beginner: will appreciate if you can explain how?

Comment: @RahulArora That's not what I mean. See my answer that is replicating the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily search in both tables at once and wait for both results using `Promise.all`:

```
db.token.findOne({
    where:{
        tokenHash: cryptojs.MD5(req.get('Auth') || '').toString()
    }
}).then(function(tokenInstance){
    if (!tokenInstance)
        throw new Error("found no token");

    req.token = tokenInstance;
    return Promise.all([
        db.company_auth.findByToken(token), //looks in the first table (company)
        db.user.findByToken(token) // also looks in the second table - user)
    ]);
}).then(function([entity, user]){
    if (entity === null){
        req.user = user;
    } else {
        req.entity = entity;
        next();
        req.user = undefined;
    }
    next(); 
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    res.status(401).send();
});
```